# RecyclerView not calling oncreateview after layout is rendered and new adapter is made

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

My application is event-driven application I have a download manager and a download activity.

**Problem:**
my download manager informs my download activity when the download list is made.
if I open download activity before the list in download manager is made then later my download manager informs my download activity that new list of download item is made but no view is rendered on the screen means no recycler view items are created on screen at runtime neither the oncreateview holder is called in recycler view.

but if I open download activity after the list in download manager then everything works fine.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.downloading_layout);

            InitializeComponents();

            SubscribeEvents();

            AssignAdapter();
        }


        private void InitializeComponents()
        {
            _noDownloadTV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_no_download);

            _downloadingList = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerview_downloading);

            _downloadingList.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
```

these functions get called after the list is created or updated in the download manager

```
private void OnCurrentDownloadRequest_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_listAdapter == null)
        AssignAdapter();
    else
        _listAdapter.UpdateList(DownloadManager.Instance.currentRequest.DownloadFiles);
}
```

AssignAdapter function

```
private void AssignAdapter()
{
    var currentRequest = DownloadManager.Instance.currentRequest;
    if (currentRequest != null && currentRequest.DownloadFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        _listAdapter = new DownloadListAdapter(this, currentRequest.DownloadFiles);
        _downloadingList.SetAdapter(_listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Recyclerview implementation

```
   public DownloadListAdapter(Context context, List<DownloadFileDetail> list) 
    {
        _context = context;
        _list = list;
    }

    public void UpdateList(List<DownloadFileDetail> list) 
    {
        _list = list;
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public override int ItemCount 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _list.Count;
        }
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        try
        {
            if (holder is DownloadListViewHolder viewHolder)
            {
                var item = _list[position];
                viewHolder.downloadItemName.Text = item.Name;
                viewHolder.downloadItemStatus.Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(DownloadFileStatus), item.Status);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.download_list_item, parent, false);

        var vh = new DownloadListViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was setting adapter outside the UI thread and it was throwing a exception so after calling set adapter inside UI thread using

```
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                _downloadingList.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                _downloadingList.SetAdapter(_listAdapter);
            });
```

views got rendered